Iterate over an array of objects using destructuring
I have an array of objects on which need to:

Iterate through the users array and obtain all the keys of the object using destructuring.

Find people who have less than two skills.


For the moment, I have completed task 1, just I don't know now how to do task 2.
Code so far:
const users = [
  {
    name: "Brook",
    scores: 75,
    skills: ["HTM", "CSS", "JS"],
    age: 16,
  },
  {
    name: "Alex",
    scores: 80,
    skills: ["HTM", "CSS", "JS"],
    age: 18,
  },
  {
    name: "David",
    scores: 75,
    skills: ["HTM", "CSS"],
    age: 22,
  },
  {
    name: "John",
    scores: 85,
    skills: ["HTML"],
    age: 25,
  },
  {
    name: "Sara",
    scores: 95,
    skills: ["HTM", "CSS", "JS"],
    age: 26,
  },
  {
    name: "Martha",
    scores: 80,
    skills: ["HTM", "CSS", "JS"],
    age: 18,
  },
  {
    name: "Thomas",
    scores: 90,
    skills: ["HTM", "CSS", "JS"],
    age: 20,
  },
];

I have completed task 1
for(let {name, scores, skills, age} of users){
    console.log(name, scores, skills, age);
}

